# iOS 8 UITableView background color appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

Xcode 6 beta 6, trying to change all UITableView's background colours in appearance proxy:

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]
```

But seems that it doesn't work.

Steps to reproduce:

1 Create single view project

2 Add UITableView to ViewController in **storyboard**

3 Set delegates to view controller and change background in IB:

[image]

4 Add dynamic cell and configure data source:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1Identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return 60.f;
}
```

5 In app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  [[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

  return YES;
}
```

6 Run app and watch incorrect colour:

[image]

Any suggestions how to fix it?
Setting background color for every table doesn't look like good solution.

Comment: It occurs only for iOS 8.0.x which was buggy, not producing in lower or greater version of 8.0.x and I think most of the users upgraded to 8.1 so not to worry at all:)

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924926/ios-8-setting-background-color-uitableview-via-uiappearance) question it seems to be a bug. rdar://18406065

Comment: I still get the UITableView appearance background color issue in iOS 8.1.X and 8.2.X on physical device and simulator. However it works fine above. I have to keep a `[tableview setBackgroundColor: ]` programmatically.

Comment: popei, The question is how to do it automatically in appearance proxy

Answer (score 12):

try to "reset" the BackgroundColor to "Default" in the InterfaceBuilder (even if its already Default, you'll see a little color change)

this doesn't works with grouped style tableviews

**UPDATE:**

this worked for me

```
[[UIScrollView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Even with default colour, it doesn't work right now.

Comment: but the problem is for grouped style tables

Comment: This did not work for me either. For some reason iOS 8 "broke" the ability to set the background color on the table view for us. Any other ideas?

Comment: setting appearance of UIScrollView allowed me to change the tableview background color - however, I did not manage to create a tableview with a transparent background (setting SetOpaque on UIScrollView appearance doesn't seem to do the trick)

Answer (score 5):

Clear color for TableViewCell not working in Tablet in XCode 6. The following workaround solve for me.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that for iOS 8, at least for our circumstances, when we set a view's background color with a table in that view, we have to **explicitly** set the table and cell background colors to Clear in order for the desired color from the view to show. I suppose, with prior iOS versions, the cells were defaulted to transparent but that seems no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

Set cell background color to transparent in 
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

[UITableVIew backgroundColor] is not marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. Appearance proxies will only work if selector is marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem because UITableView inherits from UIView, which has  a property backgroundColor marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the appearance proxy exhibits a seemingly unreported bug in iOS 8.0.x; it's unrelated to the iOS 7 change involving the default background colour of table cells.

The relative good news is that this only seems to be an issue between iOS 8.0 and 8.0.2, because:

1. My iPhone 4S on 7.1.2 doesn't have this issue,
2. My colleague's iPhone 6 running 8.1 doesn't have this issue.

Until most users have upgraded you will have to set the background explicitly on the object itself, sending us back into the pre-appearance era :(

Comment: Interesting... I'm seeing it in all my 8.1 simulators.