# iOS 8: setting background color UITableView via UIAppearance

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

i am used to doing the following to style all instances of `UITableView`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    return YES;
}
```

but **on ios 8** this is **not working** anymore.

for the purpose of testing and demo i created a new master-detail project using xcode 6.0.1 which you can find [on github](https://github.com/glaszig/iOS8-UITableView-backgroundColor).
running it on ios 7 works (table view gets blue background). on ios 8 not so much.

did i miss someting during the hype? is this a bug?

#### Update 2014-09-25

this appears to be a known bug. the apple radar # is 17974434 which is currently marked as *open*.

Comment: Make sure that line is called before the table is created.

Comment: it is in `application:didFinishLaunching` as you can see in the commit.

Comment: Instead of making people go offsite and review your entire project (which i didn't do), you should update your question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, reported another bug to Apple (rdar://18537175): http://openradar.appspot.com/18537175

Comment: After further investigation (AKA diff between headers), I've noticed that in iOS 8 a backgroundColor property has been added to UITableView (previously it was inherited from UIView):


`@property (nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor; // default background color is dependent on style`


This property, differently from UIView one, misses the UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR macro. I don't know if this is on purpose (the comment may suggest this, but it's not clear to me) or it is an error. Let's see what Apple answer.

Comment: i'm fine with the "default depending on style" but `UIAppearance` should be an option. feels like a regression to me.

Comment: @charex backgroundColor property is actually on UITableViewRowAction object that is located in UITableView.h file not on UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.1 is working like this:

```
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    UITableView.appearance().tintColor =  UIColor.white
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.1 is working like this:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
UITableView.appearance().tintColor =  UIColor.white
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```